# php & mysql query not echoing in html with tags?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$data = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE country = '{$country}' AND state = '{$state}' AND city = '{$city}' LIMIT {$limit}");
while( $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
$proxy = $assoc['proxy'];
echo '<<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sock5Proxies</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<center>
<h1>Sock5Proxies</h1>
</center>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul id="nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span></span>Home</a></li> 
           <li><a href="leads.html"><span></span>Leads</a></li> 
           <li><a href="payout.php"><span></span>Pay out</a></li> 
           <li><a href="contact.html"><span></span>Contact</a></li> 
           <li><a href="logout.php"><span></span>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:690px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="75" class="first">Proxy</th>
                        <th width="50" class="last">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="rowB">
                        <td class="first"> <?php echo $proxy ?> </td>
                        <td class="last">Check</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>
    </center>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <span id="about">Version 1.0</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>';
}
}
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="limit" placeholder="10"/><br>
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country"/><br>
<input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State"/><br>
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"/><br>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /><br>
</form>
</html>
```

I'm receiving no errors now on line 47, this is supposed to be printing out my query, it works without the html & styling, before you ask yes the theme does work, as of style.css.

Comment: Are you sure that <td class="first"> <?php echo $proxy ?> </td> is really what you want to do? The thing is, you're wrapping your echo string in single quotes, so this bit will not be parsed and it will echo as it is now.

Comment: @tf.alves Right I see, is there another way to echo into this themed table? Thanks.

Comment: Also, drop the `<<` before the DOCTYPE -- it should be just `<!DOCTYPE html ...`

Comment: yes there is, I'll post an answer, I'm kinda new here, I don't know how to post code correctly in a comment.
Edit: Barmar got ahead of me, look at his answer :)

Comment: @tf.alves In general, avoid trying to post more than tiny snippets of code in comments. You can mark code with backticks, but there's no formatting so anything long is difficult to read.

Comment: `echo long-string` could/should be replaced with simply `?>long-string`.

Answer (score 2):

`<td class="first"> <?php echo $proxy ?> </td>` is *inside* a literal string that you are `echo`ing.  End the string, or concatenate it correctly:

`<td class="first">' . $proxy . '</td>`

Answer (score 1):

Change `<?php echo $proxy ?>` to `' . $proxy . '`.

You use `<?php` when you're outputting HTML by leaving PHP mode with `?>`. When you using `echo`, you have to use concatenation, or wrap your string in double quotes and use interpolation.

Comment: Ah, I see silly be I'm trying to put PHP tags in a PHP echoed script what am I doing must be all of that new years drink, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I can spot a few different problems with this. However, in the interest of time, try this chunk of code instead:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $limit = $_POST['limit'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $data = mysqli_query(
        $link,
        "SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE country = '{$country}' AND state = '{$state}' AND city = '{$city}' LIMIT {$limit}"
    );
    while ($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        $proxy = $assoc['proxy'];
        ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                    <title>Sock5Proxies</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
                    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                    <link href="./buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <center>
                        <h1>Sock5Proxies</h1>
                    </center>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="header">
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span></span>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="leads.html"><span></span>Leads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="payout.php"><span></span>Pay out</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html"><span></span>Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="logout.php"><span></span>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content">
                            <div id="center">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:690px">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="75" class="first">Proxy</th>
                                        <th width="50" class="last">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr class="rowB">
                                        <td class="first"> <?php echo $proxy ?> </td>
                                        <td class="last">Check</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="footer"></div>
                        <span id="about">Version 1.0</span>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="limit" placeholder="10" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /><br>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your variables to the echoed string. For example:

```
echo 'This is a string '.$PHPvariable.' and this is more string';
```